# Vee-Validate not working with form wizard

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I'm validating multi step form with vee validate, I want to do step wise validation for step 1 need to validate only first step field i have implemented it in this codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-https-oc4u2?file=/src/App.vue

But the issue is i cannot move to next step because validation function is also validating second step field in first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validate` has an [option](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/programmatic-validation.html#validation-options) to validate only specific fields. If it is empty `validate()` it will validate all fields. So you can try `this.$validator.validate("title", this.formData.name)`